# How to use grequest.post for multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, csv, python-requests

```
ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://example.com'
headers = {'Api-key': '123abc'}

with open("student.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r ]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['name'])):
        #My data mapping

        #for loop to post each record
        rs = (grequests.post(u,json=groups, headers=headers) for u in ENDPOINT_URL)
        grequests.map(rs)

        print(grequests.map(rs)
```

The resulting return `None` Which part I doing wrong?Is it possible the json data format issue?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?  what is the end goal?

Comment: I'm trying to do the multiprocessing for api post request. Before this, my code working is `post_api = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers)` but it only post the data one by one.